# Copy value of cell to another cell

Tags: google-apps-script

The code:

```
function CopyPasteA6() {
   var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');            
   var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');            
   sheet1.getRange('A6').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('A6'))
}
```

This will copy the entire cell, including the formula. If I just want to copy the cell value and leave out if there is any formula, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function CopyPasteA6() {
   var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');            
   var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');            
   sheet2.getRange('A6').setValue(sheet1.getRange('A6').getValue());
}
```